# Ways to filter http traffic programmatically

Tags: networking, proxy, traffic-filtering

How many ways are there to programmatically filter http trafic over device? Not only to capture packets and ban by regex as wireshark but to build a filter that for example requests a page, extracts certain information and based on it holds or give you traffic?

For now the only way to do this, as I see, is to use proxy servers libs that allows response/request modifying and exists in most programming languages.

Comment: yep, any means you use to do this will involve a proxy, whether its a local one like Fiddler or Charles, or an upstream one like Squid or whatever, you are still funneling your traffic in the clear through the proxy process.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It is free and includes a scripting framework called FiddlerScript that allows you to modify or block HTTP requests or responses.